# how to select count of specific value while joining two tables

Tags: mysql

here i am joining two tables and this code fails to get the count of c.status
when c.status='Absent'

```
SELECT    d.empReferenceID,
          Count(c.status) 
FROM      emp_tbl d  
LEFT JOIN empattendance c 
on        d.empReferenceID = c.RefrenceID 
and       c.status='PRESENT' 
and       month(c.CreatedOn)=5 
and       year(c.CreatedOn)=2017 
where     c.RefrenceID not in ('2075671') 
GROUP BY  d.empReferenceID;
```

Comment: Your query selects `c.status='PRESENT'` and you expect it to count `c.status='Absent'`? How should this be possible?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve `PRESENT` and `Absent` count separetely in each group?

Comment: @ Thorsten Kettner yes I know I need to remove  c.status='PRESENT'  this condition while joining but I am confused how to get a count of  c.status

Comment: @ Forward  for Absent Count(c.status) should be zero

Comment: Cold you please show some sample data and the expected result? With `GROUP BY  d.empReferenceID` you get one result line per `empReferenceID`. Is this desired? Or do you want one row per `empReferenceID` + `status` instead? Or just one row per `status`?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner Thanks for your reply I am new to stack overflow

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner  my query is i want to join two table empattendance and emp_tbl for if employee is absent his count of present should be 0

Comment: You query fails to count 0, because of `c.RefrenceID not in ('2075671')`. When there is no row for the status, then `c.RefrenceID` is null. `null not in ('2075671')` however doesn't result in true, but in "unknown", because it is not known whether the unkown value represented by null is present in the set or not.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner okk  I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put conditions on an outer-joined table in the WHERE clause. Your `where c.RefrenceID not in ('2075671')` dismisses all outer-joined records and turns the join into an inner join.

Maybe you are looking for conditional aggregation, where you count different statuses and show the counts in the same result row:

```
SELECT    d.empReferenceID,
          Count(c.status) AS count_all,
          Sum(c.status = 'PRESENT') AS count_present,
          Sum(c.status = 'Absent') AS count_absent
FROM      emp_tbl d  
LEFT JOIN empattendance c 
ON        d.empReferenceID = c.RefrenceID 
AND       month(c.CreatedOn)=5 
AND       year(c.CreatedOn)=2017 
WHERE     d.empReferenceID not in ('2075671') 
GROUP BY  d.empReferenceID;
```

The `SUM` lines make use of MySQL's `true = 1`/ `false = 0` by the way. You'd achieve the same with standard SQL: `Sum(CASE WHEN c.status = 'PRESENT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` or `Count(CASE WHEN c.status = 'PRESENT' THEN 1 END)`.